# Solving simultaneously some equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have some equations (18) and want to obtain a variable (X7) simultaneously for all equations by NSolve or Find Root. but I can not. Any one can help me?
my equations

```
list={7.56433 (589.293 - 0.0041175 X7), 7.56987 (589.036 - 0.0082753 X7),  
 7.58102 (588.519 - 0.01652 X7),  7.59251 (587.989 - 0.0248558 X7),   
 7.60164 (587.568 - 0.0313713 X7),  7.62271 (586.601 - 0.0460045 X7),  
 7.64229 (585.707 - 0.059133 X7),  7.68135 (583.938 - 0.0839613 X7), 
 7.70909 (582.692 - 0.100513 X7),  7.73606 (581.489 - 0.115759 X7),   
 7.75375 (580.705 - 0.125312 X7),  7.90386 (574.192 - 0.192599 X7),  
 8.07896 (566.9 - 0.241794 X7),  8.2409 (560.432 - 0.261542 X7),  
 8.40556 (554.11 - 0.258404 X7),  8.55886 (548.444 - 0.236144 X7),  
 8.68673 (543.87 - 0.204388 X7),  8.93182 (535.47 - 0.112937 X7)}
```

The code that I applied is:

```
NSolve[list[i]==0,{i,1,Length[list]},X7]
```

or

```
FindRoot[list[i]==0,{i,1,Length[list]},X7]
```

Each equation is independent but X7 is for all equations.

Comment: As you can see by running `NSolve[# == 0, X7] & /@ list`, there is no single value of `X7` that is a common solution to all your equations. They are actually not even close, so the system of simultaneous equations (i.e. `NSolve[list == 0, X7]`) has no solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the "best" X7 that fits all of your equations, you can try:

```
NMinimize[Total[Abs[list]], X7]

{42760.6, {X7 -> 2660.97}}
```

which shows you that there is no X7 that does a great job solving all the equations at once.

Comment: Put another way, what bill did here is to find the minimum $1$-norm solution to the set of overdetermined equations in the OP. One could also consider least-squares (`NMinimize[Norm[list, 2], X7]`) or the Chebyshev norm solution (`NMinimize[Max[Abs[list]], X7]`), among the other common choices.